# Ubuntu 20.04: Service only runs after user first logs in

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm trying to setup an openvpn server which uses nat to give users access to a number of VPC's in AWS.

To do this I'm running the command...

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
```

... where 10.10.0.0/24 is the range of private IP's assigned by openvpn.

I'm having trouble though getting this iptables command to run automatically when the server reboots.

The way I'm currently doing it, is with the following service...

`/etc/systemd/system/vpn_iptables.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Set up the firewall
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/vpn_iptables

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script itself is defined like so...

`/usr/local/sbin/vpn_iptables`:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
```

I've been breaking my head trying to figure out the seemingly inconsistent behavior. The masquerading seemed to work, and then all of a sudden it wouldn't.

What I finally figured out is that I need to have ssh'd into the server at least once after rebooting, and then it works correctly.

This is making it very difficult to debug what's going wrong.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the way I've defined my `vpn_iptables.service`, but I don't know enough about it to understand what I've done wrong.

What I want to do, is have the service always start as soon as the network is available, but it should not wait until a user has logged in.

My understanding is that `WantedBy=multi-user.target` is to ensure that the system is ready to accept user connections, but I don't know why it would actually require a user to have logged in.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Also I should just mention I've tried various other ways to run this automatically, including putting it in /etc/rc.local, and in a cloud-init per-boot script etc. Nothing else seems to have worked. I'm assuming this is something to do with the timing of when these various scripts run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's helpful to others, I found a solution...

I just needed to change the WantedBy to...

```
[Install]
WantedBy=openvpn.service
```

It makes perfect sense really, now that I understand a bit better what this actually means.